# How to pass in a client id to Google IOS Sign In

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-signin

I am following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in to integrate Google Sign In in my swift IOS application. How can I change the client id before I show the login form?

Comment: Are you asking how to change it at runtime? To use a different client id than the one in your info.plist?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I want to change it at runtime to use a different client id than the one in plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use a `GoogleService-Info` file with a single Client Id.  If you need different client Ids for different versions of your app, say dev & release, then you can use different `GoogleService-Info` files for the different build schemes.

If you do want to use different client ids via code then you need to create your own `GIDSigninConfig` and set it on the `GIDSignin` instance:

```
let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: "abc123")
let signin = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance
signin.config = config
...
```